# Issue with Solidity 6.0 (returns not work)

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have strange issue with Solidity 0.6.0

**When I try get result from 0.6.0 contract the same code not work, but works for 0.4.24.**

Remix does not show any warnings, and I can deploy code without problem.

I deployed and verified simple contracts for test.

Solidity 0.6.0

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xb1e8c98583652c27cdcbeaf0b2e50dc2b3d010c7#code

Solidity 0.4.24

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x7c698e9be23376a25b48b98916e01eb471b1bfde#code

Reproduce

> Try call function
>
> getCTokenExchangeRateCurrent
>
> With this param address
>
> 0xa253295ec2157b8b69c44b2cb35360016daa25b1

Video with my attempts: https://youtu.be/01Lo_WdzHQk

Comment: Can you show the source code of the callable contract on the address 0xA253295eC2157B8b69C44b2cb35360016DAa25b1 ? What compiler version have you used to compile that contract?

Comment: This is Compound token https://compound.finance/docs

I didn't deploy this token

Comment: This is contract for mainnet

https://etherscan.io/address/0xcce67f9095a71a6aa3bdd9d072c905cb4f761a5a#code

The same result

Answer (score 1):

This is was my mistake.

I call function without view modifier

https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-protocol/blob/master/contracts/CTokenInterfaces.sol#L226

For Solidity 4 this works, for 6 not.